# how to test if can connect to port in rhel 7 (telnet client?)

Tags: networking, rhel

On my local machine some network application is launched on port 3333 and I want to check that it "accepts connections". In this case in Windows I just type `telnet` to launch telnet client, and then `o localhost 3333` to test if I can connect.

How can I do the same in `RHEL 7`? Should I also use `telnet` or probably there is another tool? [This article](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1269) suggest to execute `yum install xinetd telnet telnet-server` but I'm afraid if this will open any ports? I don't want to install any "server" functionality, only "client" telnet application. And definitely I do not want telnet to open any ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install just the `telnet` package and have telnet client functionality. Alternately, you can use the `nc` command to test port connectivity if you'd rather not mess with telnet at all.

Comment: thanks, tried that. by some reason `nc localhost 3333` tells "Connection refused", but when I execute `telnet` and `o localhost 3333` i'm able to connect. Do you know what `nc` doesn't work?

Comment: @javapowered `nc` or `telnet` might be using IPv4 or IPv6, or might be making different DNS or /etc/hosts lookups. We'd need more information, such as from `netstat` and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo -n > /dev/tcp/[hostname/ip]/[port]
```

return errorcode 0  if successful

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted.  I was going to mention the same thing.  (I've upvoted.)  It's a Bash feature; I believe it was introduced in Bash 4.  Welcome to the site; thanks for posting this!

Comment: That looks like it could work for some Unix flavors, but how is it "a Bash feature"? It clearly relies on the OS exposing connections in `/dev/tcp` ... and not on much else.